# Why the use of "&" inside a function parameter

Tags: c++

I'm looking through the c++ tutorial [http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/ under "The keyword this"] and I'm confused on why a member function parameter has "&".

The code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class CDummy {
public:
    int isitme( CDummy& param );    // <-- Having trouble understanding this
};

int CDummy::isitme( CDummy& param )    // <-- Having trouble understanding this
{
    if( &param == this) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main ()
{
    CDummy a;
    CDummy *b = &a;
    if ( b->isitme(a) )
        std::cout<< "yes, &a is b";

    return 0;   
}
```

Why does `int isitme( CDummy& param)` work and not `int isitme( CDummy param )`? Also how come in the function implementation it goes `if( &param == this )`, shouldn't `&param` only be used if the function declaration were `int isitme( CDummy param )`?

Comment: Look up references in whatever educational material you have on hand.

Comment: But when you pass in a to b->isitme(). It is not a reference, right?

Comment: Splaty, yes, it _is_ a reference. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reference.

Normally, C++ is a pass-by-value language meaning that a *copy* is given to the functon.

By using `&`, you specify that the `param` variable is a reference, *almost <sup>(a)</sup>* like a pointer but without having to worry about indirection. The reference means you have access to the *original* variable for modification if necessary or (in this case) so that you can compare its address.

If you had passed by value, you would have gotten a *copy* which would have had a different address. What the `isitme()` method is doing is simply checking if a given `CDummy` variable is the one you're calling the method for, by checking the addresses of them as per the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class CDummy {
public:
    int isitme (CDummy &x) {
        return &x == this;
    }
};

int main (void) {
    CDummy a, b;
    std::cout << a.isitme (a) << '\n';   // 1 = true
    std::cout << a.isitme (b) << '\n';   // 0 = false
    return 0;
}
```

The output of that is:

```
1
0
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The main difference being that a reference *has* to refer to a real variable while a pointer may be NULL.

Comment: I've never seen the & used in a function parameter before. I always thought pointers were what is widely used. By saying "without having to worry about indirection" do you mean not worrying about the asterisk?

Comment: @Splaty, pointers were the way you did pass-by-reference in C but it had its problems, such as requiring indirection to get at the underlying variable. I consider references one of the _best_ features of C++, certainly one they should consider for ISO C23 :-)

Answer (score 1):

That is using the C++ lvalue reference language feature to pass a lvalue by-reference to the function, rather than having to use an explicit pointer like in C.  Since references must be bound to objects, they cannot have a `NULL` value ... the reference-type variable basically aliases the object it references (i.e., there is no explicit dereferencing by the user like a pointer requires).